# Wrap method signature in the quick documantation

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation

Is there any setting available to wrap the method signature in the quick documentation.

[image]

In don't find any relavent setting in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-inline-documentation.html?origin=old_help)